# 400 response when adding new venue

Tags: foursquare

I'm trying to add new venue via venue/add endpoint. I've received following reply:

> {"meta":{"code":400,"errorType":"param_error","errorDetail":"Top level category Residences cannot be used as venue category"},"response":{}}

Does it mean I can't create venue in all of 9 top level categories, or maybe I can't create venue in any category that has child categories?
Are there any other categories I should filter out when adding venue?

Comment: Can you show how you are trying to add the venue.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that's right. You cannot use any of the top level categories when creating venue. use a more specific category.